# How to delete items without mutation from a paginated list in Apollo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I get array from a paginated list in Apollo. then, I want to delete items.
like this,

```
edges: [
    ...edges.slice(0, index),
    ...edges.slice(index + 1)
  ]
```

**I need to update only local array.**

Comment: You can just clone the array. One way is `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(edges))`

Comment: what is happening wrong? this looks ok to me unless the scope of the name `edges` is your problem (i.e. you are using the same name in the same scope)

Comment: edges is name of array from paginated. I want to delete item from edges. But I get no answer from website. I read document of Apollo and I see the function of writeQuery, but I get a trouble that it has cursor in variables in my query when I use it. I get data from react high order component(@graphql).I no method to this question.